# How to configure PutFile such that it runs on a 24 hr schedule however it runs as many time as number of incoming flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

How to configure PutFile such that it runs on a 24 hr schedule however it should execute as many time as the number of incoming flowfiles.  Currently if PutFile is set on 24 hr schedule then it only produces one file (for the first incoming flowfile), my use case is requirement is to have it run once a day for all incoming flowfiles.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of solving this is to use the **Run Duration** and **Concurrent Tasks** configuration under the process scheduling tab.

[image]

When you set the **Run Duration** for 2s, the PutFile process will continue to run for two seconds once it is started (After 24 hours in your case). And you can increase the number of **Concurrent Tasks** to a higher level (Ex: 100) so that within two seconds the processor will be able to process more files concurrently.

NOTE: This solution cannot guarantee that all the flow files in the queue are going to be processed but it will process large number of files within two seconds.